# DeleteUser method in FOSuserBundle symfony 2 Userinterface error

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a problem with deleting user with $UserManager->deleteUser($user). I'm getting an error: Error: Class AppBundle\Controller\UsermanagerController contains 35 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods.

My Controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\UserManager;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class UsermanagerController extends Controller implements UserInterface
{
public function deleteAction($user){
$UserManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
if ($user ==  null) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('User not found for user ' . $user);
    }
$UserManager->deleteUser($user);
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_index'));

}
```

My Entity:

```
namespace AppBundle/Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager as BaseCustomer;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;

/**
*@ORM|Entitiy
*
*/
class UserManager extends BaseCustomer implements UserInterface
{

}
```

My config.yml:
 orm:

```
resolve_target_entities:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: AppBundle\Entity\UserManager
```

And Routing.yml:

```
fos_deleteuser_group:
    path: /app/usermanager/delete/{user}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Usermanager:delete }
```

I tried to use FOS/UserBundle/doctrine/UserManager, no luck.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize:

Your first error was that `implements UserInterface` in the controller. you've removed it.

Then you have another problem inside of your controller because you pass a string to the `UserManager::deleteUser` method which expects some `UserInterface`

I will provide some code for you, which should fix that.

```
<?php
/**
 * @param $username string
 * @return Response
 */
public function deleteAction($username) {
  $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
  /* @var $userManager UserManager */

  $user = $userManager->findUserByUsername($username);
  if(\is_null($user)) {
    // user not found, generate $notFoundResponse
    return $notFoundResponse;
  }

  \assert(!\is_null($user));
  $userManager->deleteUser($user);

  // okay, generate $okayResponse
  return $okayResponse;
}
```

Comment: If i drop it I get an error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager::deleteUser() must implement interface FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface, string given, called in AppBundle\Controller\UsermanagerController.php on line 34 and defined. 
Because the initial method that i'm calling  in  FOSuserbundle is  Deleteuser(UserInterface $user)

Comment: Sorry that is another point. Just with producing another error you don't get it fixed. Why don't you read the message and try to fix it? Of cource you cannot pass a string then. Use one of those `findUser*` methods for getting the user (e.g. `findUserByUsername`).

Comment: I'm sorry I tried everythig that I could find on this topic ,even copying all userinterface functions,... But I'm a beginner in Symfony 2, still learning how the framework works...Your solution Works like a charm. Thank you!
Can you just explain what this \assert(!\is_null($user)); does? Thanks

Comment: I always try to write code that enters on top and returns at the bottom. If there might occur some errors to return early I don't want to indent all of my code in one ore more huge if-blocks, which wouldn't be readable. So I check for errors and return immediately. The `if` has no else then and I may write down assertions to make clear what I expect my variables to be. In this case it might be clear enough to drop the `assert`. There are many expressions like fail-fast or early error detection to argue for `assert`.